# How to check if Oculus Go controller on OVRInputModule is clicking on GUI object or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculusgo

I'm a beginner of Unity and I've been trying to make an app for the Oculus go. So I implemented the Oculus go Controller working and some buttons on the screen. I can click the buttons and call the functions connected to the buttons. 
What I wanna do is I want to trigger some action when the controller clicked on not UI buttons.

I've tried these methods but I got false every time even if the button shows highlight color when the pointer is on the button.

```
Physics.Raycast(..)
EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject
```

```
Ray laserPointer = new Ray(rightHandAnchor.position, rightHandAnchor.forward);
RaycastHit hit;
bool hitOrNot = Physics.Raycast(laserPointer, out hit, maxRayDistance);
```

and

```
bool hitOrNot = EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the `OVRInputModule` in your scene's `EventSystem` object (you can delete the "Standard Input Module".

This will allow the laser pointer to interface with the `UI` system using standard-like events.

The other thing to note is in order for your laser pointer to interact with *normal game objects* (non-UI), you **must add** the `OVRPhysicsRaycaster` to your `OVRCameraRig` object in your scene.

For the `OVRInputModule`, you will need set the "Ray Transform" property to either the `rightHandAnchor` or `leftHandAnchor` in your `LocalAvatar` object.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that your canvas(es) need to have the `OVRRaycaster` component added as well. The `OVRInputModule` will basically overload all the normal input events, so your canvas buttons will respond to `IPointerEnterHandler` events just like they would if you were using a mouse.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class YourButton : MonoBehavior, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Raycast hit!");
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

With all of this you shouldn't really need to manually do raycasting in your script unless you have special needs for it.

Furthermore, whatever "Event Mask" you select for your `OVRPhysicsRaycaster` in the camera rig, any normal (non-UI) 3D object that is in that layer will detect the same `IPointerEnterHandler` and `IPointer...Handler` events just like a UI button, so you can use the same code for those objects as well, not *just* the UI objects.

Comment: I've already added everything you suggested. I can click UI butto. Besides I can get the name of 3D object. but I can't get the name of UI object when the laser is over the object

Comment: Make sure to add the `OVRRaycaster` to your canvas as well.

Comment: I'm trying to detect when the laser pointer is simply hovering over the button but somehow I can't. I need to press the trigger button in order to get the methods called. Also, they all get called at the same time. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698832/detecting-hovering-on-button-event-on-oculus-quest-unity3d

Comment: @DiscreteHa did you find a solution? I think we had the same problem