# Detecting hovering on button event on Oculus Quest (Unity3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus, oculusquest

Stack:

- Oculus Quest
- Unity 2019.3
- Oculus VR Integration
- macOS Catilina

I have a Unity scene with a VR interface composed by a Canvas (World Space coordinates) and two buttons.  The canvas has attached an OVR Raycaster objects which uses a laser pointer. Overall it works well, but when I try to intercept the event produced by hovering the laser pointer on the button, I can get only the click event.

I'm using the following script (attached to the button):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class VRButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerClickHandler, ISelectHandler
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enter!");
        transform.localScale *= 1.2f;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Exit!");
        transform.localScale /= 1.2f;
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that both OnPointerEnter and OnPointerClick get called when I point the button with the laser and click. Just hovering the doesn't trigger any event (nor OnPointerExit or OnPointerEnter).

This is my ADB log:

```
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : Clicked!
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.OVRInputModule:ProcessMousePress(MouseButtonEventData)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.OVRInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent(MouseState)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   :  
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : 
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : Enter!
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : VRButton:OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1:Invoke(T1, BaseEventData)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseInputModule:HandlePointerExitAndEnter(PointerEventData, GameObject)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.OVRInputModule:ProcessMousePress(MouseButtonEventData)
03-15 22:59:53.085 13339 13355 I Unity   : UnityEngine.EventSystems.OVRInputModule:ProcessMouseEvent(MouseState)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: As you are using 2019.3, I suspect that you're using the new input system? or the old one? Also here is a bunch of information about Oculus+Canvas: https://developer.oculus.com/blog/unitys-ui-system-in-vr/

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure, I have followed standard tutorials for the VR UI canvas and everything works fine except that event. Thanks for the link, although it is from 2015  so not sure about its validity

Comment: MacOS isn't fully supported I wouldn't recommend using it.  Windows is the way to go with VR development unfortunately.  And that Oculus blog for Unity UI stuff is still totally relevant.

Comment: So do you think it's just a bug?

Comment: @Claus Yes I do think that. Give it a try on a PC and let me know please. Thanks and good luck! (Sorry for my late response)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a bug, you need to add "IPointerExitHandeler" like this:

```
public class VRButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandeler, IPointerClickHandler, ISelectHandler
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).